# inner join query in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I write query about search about specific employee but did'nt work ,I know there is an error in my query but did'nt now where it.
I have 2 tables one for company and another for employee info.
the progress will be:

- 1'st Query search in company table by department number and company
  number then get the `PK_companyID` .
- 2'ed JOIN company.`PK_companyID==employee.FK_companyID`.
- 3'ed Query will search in employee table by `FK_companyID` when the
  name enter will be the same in `employee table`.

I hope its Clear to understand

```
 var query = (from c in db.Company
            where c.departmentNO== departmentNumber && c.companyNo==companyNumber
            join x in db.Employee c.PK_companyID==x.FK_companyID
            where (x.FirstName.Contains(firstName ?? x.FirstName)
            && x.SecondName.Contains(secondName ?? x.SecondName)
            && x.ThirdName.Contains(thirdName ?? x.ThirdName)
            && x.FourthName.Contains(fourthName ?? x.FourthName))
            select x).ToList();
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: if you are using EF6 then try logging the sql queries to output window and check your logic against the query issued..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your query and your filtering by using code such below, should also result much cleaner SQL if you are not using all your filters.

```
var employees = (from c in db.Company
            join e in db.Employee on c.PK_companyID equals e.FK_companyID
            where c.departmentNO == departmentNumber && c.companyNo == companyNumber
            select e);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
    employees = employees.Where(pr => pr.FirstName.Contains(firstName));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(secondName))
    employees = employees.Where(pr => pr.SecondName.Contains(secondName));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thirdName))
    employees = employees.Where(pr => pr.ThirdName.Contains(thirdName));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fourthName))
    employees = employees.Where(pr => pr.FourthName.Contains(fourthName));

return employees.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from c in db.Company                                        
             join x in db.Employee c.PK_companyID == x.FK_companyID
         where c.departmentNO == departmentNumber && c.companyNo == companyNumber
             && (x.FirstName.Contains(firstName ?? x.FirstName)
                          && x.SecondName.Contains(secondName ?? x.SecondName)
                          && x.ThirdName.Contains(thirdName ?? x.ThirdName)
                          && x.FourthName.Contains(fourthName ?? x.FourthName))

            select x).ToList();
```

Comment: But its not Mandatory to write all 4 names.How to make it accepts that and search with the fields the user enter without force him to write all 4 fields. I used '||' but it accepts all result have one of the names was entered not like a full name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyword "equals" instead of "==" in join as below:

```
var query = (from c in db.Company                                        
             join x in db.Employee c.PK_companyID equals x.FK_companyID
         where c.departmentNO == departmentNumber && c.companyNo == companyNumber
         .......
```

Hope this will work.